# Retry a Job from where it failed In Elixir

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework

Please i’ve got a Question, i’m replacing a Predictive dialer with Elixir. It has exceeded all expectations so far. However, i’m facing an issue. This piece of code works well assuming all third party dependencies work as expected,

```
def perform(phonebook_contacts, ...) do
  alias FSModEvent.Connection, as: C

  for x <-Enum.chunk(phonebook_contacts, 100, 100, []), y <- x  do 
    unless Telephony.user_balance(account_number) <= 0 do
      Task.start_link(fn -> 
        # some background job to dailout phone number y
      end)
    # :timer.sleep(1000);
  end

  ...
end
```

`phonebook_contacts` can be a list with as many as 200K Numbers

I’m using `exq`. If something external causes the job to fail, when it gets retried, it starts from the begining of the list, is there a way i can probably retry from the last contact where the Job failed at?

Assuming `[12,34,56,78,90…]`

If the Job fails at `56`, it restarts from `12` again, it there a way of continuing from `78`(sort of where it failed),...? or a better way of handling this use case

Had suggestions of Probably storing the Job's state in redis and retrying from there, but i've got no idea of how to do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simple approach here is to spin up another process with which you can store the "success status" of each individual job. Then, during any sort of restart, you can check for whether or not the job has already ran/completed.

`Agent`'s are good, easy-to-use processes for tracking small bits of state where you don't need do perform more complex interations.

For example:

```
def perform(phonebook_contacts, ...) do
  completed_agent = Agent.new(fn -> MapSet.new() end)
  # the Enum code...
    Task.start_link(fn ->
      completed? = Agent.get(completed_agent, &(MapSet.member?(&1, y)))
      unless completed? do
        # the dialout code...

        if dialout_code_succeeded do
          Agent.update(completed_agent, &MapSet.put(&1, y))
        end
      end
  end)
end
```

Now, this is probably the *most naive* way to do this, and probably not especially performant. It's important to note that the anonymous functions provided in `Agent.get/3` and `Agent.update/3` effectively *block* the agent from any other processes, so you'll want those functions to run very quickly, or else you risk causing timeouts for other processes trying to use the agent.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a recursive Job with a start index as parameter.

if the job fail, you rescue it and call himself with the current index plus one.

in your job you dont use phonebook_contacts anymore to iterate, but this function

```
  defp enum_from(phonebook_contacts, index) do
    Enum.slice(phonebook_contacts, index, Enum.count(phonebook_contacts))
  end
```

When you're calling you job for the first time you call it at the index 0.

you catch the exception and skip the problematic number by calling the job recursively at the index after